# Is it correct to say "will call once I get back"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say "I will call you once I get back"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

**However**, in doing so, be warned that you are **also**

a.) promising to return, soon;

b.) promising to call as soon as you return.
(where *as soon as you return* means *within 1/10th of the time you have been gone,
dating from this message*).

Promises are legally actionable in many Anglophone jurisdictions.

Comment: Are you sure your name isn't spelled *Lawyer*?

Comment: I disagree with (a) and (b). All the statement indicates is that you will call after your return; you're not saying how long it will take to get back or indicating how long it will take before you call (Obviously that shouldn't be *too* long, but how long is too long is a matter of opinion).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I think Mr. Lawler is trying to be funny, and I also think that sort of thing is better done in a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Robusto: Well anyone who didn't see the lighter side in the answer would hardly be misled after reading the comments! Actually, John's proposition that the allowable timespan for "soon" relates to *the time you have been gone* **dating from this message** is a new one on me. I'd probably cut myself some slack and say *within 20% or 30%* though.

Comment: You're not the person who's interpreting your message, or at least not the one totting up the commitments, namely the addressee. I was just giving **their** likely interpretations.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But the point is I might need to refer to an "authoritative" definition to justify not having called back within the timeframe the addressee was expecting. So I wouldn't quote *your* definition here - I'd quote *my revised definition* and say they should have studied the small print (and comments) more carefully!

Answer (score 1):

*I will call you as soon as I am back* or *I will call you as soon as I get back* are more correct versions of the sentence.

Comment: More correct? That implies that there is some error in the sentence in the question, which there is not. They are alternate version of the question, but they are just longer, not better in any quantifiable way.

Comment: *once I get back* is clunky